# triple integral over a specific region

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, volume, iterated-integrals

Evaluate :

$$\begin{equation}
\iiint_{\Omega} z^{2} dV , \quad \Omega : x^{2} + y^{2} + z^{2} \leq R^{2}, \quad x^{2} + y^{2} \leq Rx \quad (R > 0).
\end{equation}$$

I have solved the question , but my method was too ugly , could you please offer me some help of inspiring me of some elegant methods ?
Thank you !

My method is here :

[image: writing]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This integral works nicely in cylindrical coordinates. In the $xy$-plane the cylinder lies inside the sphere.

The equation of the cylinder is, in polar coordinates,
$$
r\leq R\cos\theta,\qquad\qquad -\frac\pi2\leq\theta\leq\frac\pi2.
$$
The cylinder is bounded above and below by the sphere, and so  the integral becomes
\begin{align}
\iiint_\Omega z^2\,dV 
&=\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\int_0^{R\cos\theta}\int_{-\sqrt{R^2-r^2}}^{\sqrt{R^2-r^2}}r\,z^2\,dz\,dr \,d\theta\\[0.2cm]
&=\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\int_0^{R\cos\theta}\frac23\,(R^2-r^2)^{3/2}r\,dr \,d\theta\\[0.2cm]
&=\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\frac2{15}\,(R^5-(R^2-R^2\cos^2\theta)^{5/2})\,d\theta\\[0.2cm]
&=\frac{2R^5}{15}\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}(1-(1-\cos^2\theta)^{5/2})\,d\theta\\[0.2cm]
&=\frac{2R^5}{15}\bigg(\pi-2\int_{0}^{\pi/2}(1-\cos^2\theta)^{5/2}\,d\theta\bigg)\\[0.2cm]
&=\frac{2R^5}{15}\bigg(\pi-2\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin^5\theta\,d\theta\bigg)\\[0.2cm]
&=\frac{2R^5}{15}\bigg(\pi-2\int_{0}^{1}(1-t^2)^2\,dt\bigg)\\[0.2cm]
&=\frac{2R^5}{15}\bigg(\pi-\frac{16}{15}\bigg)\\[0.2cm]
\end{align}

Comment: Your answer is truly elegant and insightful. When I was contemplating it on my own, I didn't clarify the upper and lower limits of the integral. This is a bit challenging for beginners, and I'm very grateful for your help. It has been tremendously beneficial to me!

Comment: However,i have to point out that the fourth line has a mistake.That should be 2/15,and so does the final answer.

Comment: Thanks for noticing, edited. Please upvote if you found the answer useful.

Comment: @MartinArgerami I don't think it's possible to vote under 50 rep  points

Comment: @SineoftheTime: [it looks like it's 15](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up).

Comment: yeah sure!i have upvoted your answer.hope it useful for you!

Comment: Thanks. It's not that it's useful for me, it's just that it is not nice to see zero upvotes next to my answer. In any case, that's how this site works, by upvoting those answers that you find useful.

Comment: I apologize for not being able to give you a timely upvoting. I will also pay attention to the rules of the website. In any case, thank you very much!

Comment: Nothing to apologize for. And it is not really a rule, but rather how the site is supposed to work.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the plot of the corresponding region when $R = 1$ using Mathematica:

[image]

Based on it, I think that a change of coordinates to cylindrical coordinates would be interesting.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Your idea is great, but I'm wavering between spherical and cylindrical coordinates. Neither of them seems to be a very concise method. I'm contemplating whether I can establish better parameters based on the conditions of the problem to solve it more efficiently